# Function calling and foreach use with it on node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, sql-server, web-scraping, playwright

I would welcome any answers that could help me understand why this doesn't work.

So here is what I am doing.
using playwright I'm getting all the information from a table on a website. then I want to save that data to my local database.

```
//configuration for the data base
var Connection = require('tedious').Connection;  
var config = {  
    server: 'insert here db',  
    authentication: {
        type: 'default',
        options: {
            userName: 'insert user', 
            password: 'no password here'  
        }
    }
};  
//configuration is added and conection made
var connection = new Connection(config);  
connection.on('connect', function(err) {  
    console.log("Connected");  
});
//connect to db
connection.connect(); 


//call to libraries that will be used
var Request = require('tedious').Request  
var TYPES = require('tedious').TYPES;  
var request = require('request');


//fuction to insert the information scraped from website to DB
function addScrapingToDb() {  
    request = new Request("INSERT INTRO DBO.EQUIPOS_TEAMS (rank, name, points) VALUES (@rank, @name, @points);", function(err) {  
     if (err) {  
        console.log(err);}  
    });  
    request.addParameter('rank', TYPES.Int,'');  
    request.addParameter('name', TYPES.NVarChar , '');  
    request.addParameter('points', TYPES.Int, );  
    request.on('row', function(columns) {  
        columns.forEach(function(column) {  
          if (column.value === null) {  
            console.log('NULL');  
          } else {  
            console.log("id of added team is " + column.value);  
          }  
        });  
    });

    // Close the connection after the final event emitted by the request, after the callback passes
    request.on("requestCompleted", function (rowCount, more) {
        connection.close();
    });
    connection.execSql(request);  
}  




//Scraping method
const playwright = require('playwright');
 
(async () => {
    const browser = await playwright.chromium.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('https://statorium.com/english-premier-league-api-football-data#demo');

    const equipos = await page.$$eval('#jstable_1 > tbody > tr', (users) => {
        return users.map(user => {
            const rank = user.querySelector('td:nth-child(1)');
            const name = user.querySelector('td:nth-child(2)');
            const points = user.querySelector('td:nth-child(9)')
            return {
                rank: rank.textContent.trim(),
                name: name.textContent.trim(),
                points: points.textContent.trim()
            };
        });
    });
    console.log('teams scraped from website');
    console.log(`${equipos.length} teams found`);
    console.dir(equipos);
    console.log('adding teams to database dbo.equipos_teams')
    //a for each method is made to send the inf in the equipos array to the funcion and add them to the database
    equipos.forEach(addScrapingToDb(equipos.rank ,equipos.name , equipos.points));
    await browser.close();
})();
```

I have a function to add the data to the database, but I am not sure if this is how it should work and if the way I'm calling the function is the correct one. right now I'm calling the function from  here:

```
equipos.forEach(addScrapingToDb(equipos.rank ,equipos.name , equipos.points));
```

I'm trying to give all the information to the function and doing a for each in the array equipos to call one by one.

the database connection is working well and the scraping gives me this output.

```
Connected
20 teams found
[
  { rank: '1', name: 'Man City', points: '90' }, 
  { rank: '2', name: 'Liverpool', points: '89' },
  { rank: '3', name: 'Chelsea', points: '70' },
  { rank: '4', name: 'Tottenham', points: '68' },
  { rank: '5', name: 'Arsenal', points: '66' },
  { rank: '6', name: 'Man Utd', points: '58' },
  { rank: '7', name: 'West Ham', points: '56' },
  { rank: '8', name: 'Wolverhampton', points: '51' },
```

In my database I have the information this way:

```
-id autoincrement int primary key
-rank int
-name varchar(50)
-points int
```

I welcome all kinds of help that I can get to better understand my code and node.js/javascript.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Your method `addScrapingToDb()` does not take any arguments but you try to call it with arguments. Also your `forEach()` is used incorrectly. You need some input argument for the callback function within `forEach()` like this `array.forEach(arrayItem => doSomething(arrayItem));`.

Comment: thanks, for that clarification, now I know that the foreach array works with the function. now I just need to call them from the function and add them to the db. thank you.

Comment: `request.addParameter('rank', TYPES.Int,'');` should be including a value in its third parameter (an integer value in this case). Likewise for the other two  calls.